# Schedule Cluster resizing on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to resize a Node Pool so that it's set to 0 nodes at night and then up again in the morning.

Is it any way to do this within the Google Console or should I use an external Cron job?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135974/is-there-a-way-to-resize-a-gke-cluster-to-0-nodes-after-a-certain-amount-of-idle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up two Cloud Scheduler jobs (one in the morning, one at night) that use a Pub/Sub trigger to a Cloud Function, as described in [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub), that in turn uses one of the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries) to `update` the node pool by changing the number of nodes with eg. the [set_node_pool_size()](https://googleapis.dev/python/container/latest/container_v1/services.html#google.cloud.container_v1.services.cluster_manager.ClusterManagerClient.set_node_pool_size) function from the Python library, while referring to the [setSize](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters.nodePools/setSize) API call documentation for the input `SetNodePoolSizeRequest` object.

This entire setup can be done from the Cloud Console.