# Is it possible to resize GKE cluster to 0 nodes after a certain amount of idle time, after my pods are turned off

Tags: cron, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-scheduler

Looking for a solution or a bash script or yaml config where in after my application testing is completed the pods are sunset and after that the GKE cluster should scale down to 0 nodes. Do we need any kind of cronjob for this needs. I see the system related pods ares till running on the nodes how this can be moved out to a single nodes?

I tried many options , looking for a bash script ot any yaml config that might help to test.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. It is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135974/is-there-a-way-to-resize-a-gke-cluster-to-0-nodes-after-a-certain-amount-of-idle

Comment: Have you looked at using GKE Autopilot mode?  Seems like it might be the right fit for this use case.